# Unexpected vertical bar appearing in leaflet document

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a basic leaflet using the (appropriately named) [leaflet](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/leaflet) package. I immediately ran into the minor issue of an unexplained vertical "bar", similar to the pipe character, being typeset between the first and second columns of the second page. Even [the example document](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/leaflet/leaflet-manual.pdf) and a very minimal leaflet document, such as

```
\documentclass[10pt]{leaflet}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Myname}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

has this bar. (It is visible near the bottom right corner, due to page rotation.)

My question is: What is this vertical bar, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you try the package option `nofoldmark`?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I realized that this bar was called a fold mark. Of course, this removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, the vertical bar is called a "fold mark". It can be removed by changing the document class declaration to

```
\documentclass[10pt,nofoldmark]{leaflet}
```

In other words, "foldmark" is the default.